# Replacing missing values with average groups in R - error: out of boundaries

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a huge file that looks like this:

```
 V1    SNP1 SNP2 SNP3 SNP4 SNP5 SNP6 SNP7 SNP8 SNP9
GROUP1   1    NA   2     1    1   NA   1    1    2
GROUP1   1     2  NA     0    0    2   1   1     NA
GROUP1   0     2   2     0   NA    1   1   1     2
GROUP2   1     2   1     1    1   NA   2   0     2
GROUP2   1     1   1    NA    0    1   0   1    NA
GROUP2   1     1  NA     1    0    1   NA  1     0
```

What I need to do is to replace the missing values with the group average. I have done this in a small example and it works. However when I do in the big file, I get an error: “subscript out of boundaries”.
What I am doing is:
Creating a list with the groups that I want to keep for further analysis:

```
group.list = unique(data_file$V1)
```

Now I need to do the average for each column based on group:

```
A<-colMeans(data_file[data_file$V1 == group.list[1],-1],na.rm=T)
for(i in 2:length(group.list)){
  A <- rbind(A, colMeans(data_file[data_file$V1 %in% group.list[i],-1], na.rm=T))
}
rownames(A)<-group.list
```

There are some column averages (SNPs) that are missing. So I did this:

```
SNP.present <- which(A[1,]>=0)
for(i in 2:length(group.list)){
  SNP.present <- intersect(SNP.present,which(A[i,]>=0))
}
A <- A[,SNP.present]

data_file1 = data_file[,c(1,SNP.present+1)]
for(i in 1:dim(data_file1)[1]){
  a <- which(is.na(data_file1[i,]))
  if(length(a)>0){ 
    data_file1[i,a]<-A[data_file1$V1[i],a] 
  }
}
```

When I run this in a small dataset, it seems to work. However when I run the full dataset I get the error:

> Error in A[data_file1$V1[i], a] : subscript out of bounds

Anyone knows what could be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) 
          replace(x, is.na(x), mean(x, na.rm=TRUE))) , V1]
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(V1) %>% 
     mutate_each(funs(replace(., which(is.na(.)),
                                mean(., na.rm=TRUE))))
```

Comment: data.table looks better all the time. I'm going to make the jump soon to a data.frame free world, simply for your responses.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen  It is faster and most of the operations that can be done with data.frame is possible with data.table`

Comment: @akrun if i want to do the same for only 1 columns, let's say it's `SNP2` here, can you show me hot to do this with dplyr or even data.table?

Comment: @OrhanYazar  With `data.table`, you can do `setDT(df1)[,  .(SNP2 = replace(SNP2, is.na(SNP2), mean(SNP2, na.rm = TRUE))), V1]`

Comment: @akrun `Error in drop && !has.j : invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'` i got this error

Comment: @OrhanYazar  My comment is based on this example and is working fine `setDT(df1)[, .(SNP2 = replace(SNP2, is.na(SNP2), mean(SNP2, na.rm = TRUE))), V1]#
       V1 SNP2
1: GROUP1    2
2: GROUP1    2
3: GROUP1    2
4: GROUP2    2
5: GROUP2    1
6: GROUP2    1`

Comment: @akrun I figured it out, my V1 was factor i need to convert it as character thank you again